# Extract attachment from email and send it again without downloading it java mail

Tags: jakarta-mail, attachment

I have a folder with messages. I'm trying to read a message get text part, modify it and send the message again. This is simple with just plain text but when I have multipart (attachment) I would like to pass the attachment to Sender class without downloading it to a file on the hard drive and then uploading it from there.I still want to edit the text part of the message. I've tried to get the attachment bodyPart

```
}else if ((Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(disposition) || !contentType
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("text/plain"))) {

                 partToPack = (BodyPart) part;
 and pass it to Sender class.

 messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
 messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(bodyPart.getDataHandler());
```

but I get an exception:

`java.io.IOException: javax.mail.MessagingException: No MimeBodyPart content`.

I'm not sure how to pack the attachment so I can simply put it into messageBodyPart later.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this with standard IMAP and SMTP without downloading the attachment first.  There are IMAP and SMTP protocol extensions that enable this, but they're not widely implemented by mail servers, and JavaMail doesn't support them.

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent a lot of time searching for an answer!